# How can I create a Map keyed with pairs of integers?

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary

JavaScript `Map`s compare object keys by identity, which means `Map<[number, number], T>` is a bad idea:

```
const map = new Map();
const coordinates = [1, 3];

map.set(coordinates, 0);
map.get([1, 3]);
# undefined
```

To avoid this, we commonly see keys set as `` `${a}_${b}` ``. That's reasonably fast, but it involves number-to-string conversion. If we know the range of A and B, we could do `(a << 8) + b` which is 2-3x faster in my testing: http://jsben.ch/JRG9z

For integers with unknown domain, is there a similar approach to the bitshift the uniqueness of the resulting key, but doesn't involve a string cast?

Comment: (I am, of course, aware that this is unlikely to be the bottleneck in any real code, and if it is, hey, you're writing in *javascript* what did you expect. Consider this an intellectual curiosity more than anything.)

Comment: @Phil (at least in my testing) [number, number] is an array, which are compared as objects. So if you have the original [3, -1] on hand you're fine, but if you do any destructuring to it, that's a new object, which will be treated as a different key

Comment: Yep, gotcha. Thanks for clarifying. I assume the order of the two key numbers is significant?

Comment: When <https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple> arrives, you will be able to key maps with tuples directly.

Comment: @user3840170 I found out about the record/tuple proposal shortly after making this. Cannot wait.

Answer (score 3):

> For integers with unknown domain, is there a similar approach to the bitshift the uniqueness of the resulting key, but doesn't involve a string cast?

No. Integers with an unknown domain carry at least 53 bits of information, so there's no way to fit two integers into a single JS number (max 64 bits of information) without collisions.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. I don't necessarily mean (int, int) => number; I'm concerned with avoiding the successive-division style int-to-string conversion. So, for instance, BigInt, or if there was a bit-fiddling method to get a string of the raw bit-level state of the numbers using `Float64Array([a,b]).buffer`.

Comment: If you accept `(number, number) => bigint` and know that the numbers are integers, then `(a, b) => BigInt(a) << 1024n | BigInt(b)` would do. If you know that they're smaller than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, `<< 53n` is enough. If you need to work with arbitrary doubles, `(a, b) => { const u = new BigUint64Array(new Float64Array([a, b]).buffer); return u[1] << 64n | u[0]; }` sounds fine (though allocating typed arrays is costly, benchmark and compare with the string approach!).  If you want `(bigint, bigint) => bigint`, you can write a (probably quite slow) function that interleaves the bits.

Comment: Yeah, some quick testing looks like even `BigInt(a) << 53n | BigInt(b)` is slower than `${}_${}`, and `TextDecoder().decode(buf)` also doesn't seem promising speed-wise (even if you could avoid null-terminated string issues.) Looks like string casts is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a nested object for this. Could be replaced with `map` also (more coding):

```js
class CoordMap{
  map = {};
  set(coord, val){
    (this.map[coord[0]] ??= {})[coord[1]] = val;
  }
  get(coord){
    return this.map[coord[0]]?.[coord[1]];
  }
}

const map = new CoordMap;
const coordinates = [1, 3];

map.set(coordinates, 0);
console.log(map.get([1, 3]));
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, and I need to remember to use ??= within expressions more often! I suspect there's also a way to make a class that extends Map() that does structural equality by default.